# Setting a variable name as a type

Tags: c#, json.net

I am deserializing a json object from a third party API. One of the Objects properties is a variable called "checked". In c#.net 'checked' is a type. Is there anyway to overcome this.

Im using Newtonsoft Json.net to do the deserializing.

Nothing special about the class,

```
public class item{
  public bool checked;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `@` to prefix the name:

```
public class item{
  public bool @checked;
}
```

By the way [`checked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) is not a type but a keyword.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb.aspx):

> Keywords are predefined, reserved identifiers that have special meanings to the compiler. They cannot be used as identifiers in your program unless they include @ as a prefix.

Answer (score 2):

While @nemesv's answer is correct and will work fine, I just wanted to mention that there is another alternative if you are using Json.Net.  You could use a `JsonProperty` attribute to map your class property to the JSON property such that they can have different names.  For example:

```
public class item
{
    [JsonProperty("checked")]
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```